# Adding a font size to this HTML

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML that I am using in the footer of my website.  I am trying to figure out how to add a small font size to this to override my website theme.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
<a href="https://txfoodie.com/privacy-policy/">Privacy</a> & <a href="https://txfoodie.com/disclosure/">Discloure</a> Policy <br/>
```

[footer_copyright before="Copyright"  first="2018" "Copyright "] TX Foodie

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that I want the Privacy & Disclosure Policy font to be smaller and leave the Copyright piece the same size that the website forces.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Show us the full HTML of that section. Just providing those links will not help us to help you. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Give the link a class and style it with css?

Answer (score 1):

```
<span class="small">
    <a href="https://txfoodie.com/privacy-policy/">Privacy</a> & <a href="https://txfoodie.com/disclosure/">Discloure</a> Policy
</span><br>
```

and then in your style tag or css file:

```
.small{
    font-size: 10px;/*or whatever font size you want*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add a class to wrap it so that you can style it. For example:

```
    <div class="tiny-font">
        <a href="/privacy-policy/">Privacy</a> & <a href="/disclosure/">Discloure</a> Policy
    </div>
    <style>
        .tiny-font,
        .tiny-font a {
            font-size: 8px;
        }
    </style>
```

You might also notice that I have changed your urls. It would be better to use relative urls.

Comment: The URLs are probably generated via WordPress (since OP posted a shortcode snippet) - it's not better or worse to use relative URLs.